# ajax not perfoming request with typeahead using Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm asking this question here because I have been hours into this problem and I have asked this in other places but no one seem to knows the answer.

I'm trying to make a request with `Ajax` to autocomplete  a form.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('autocomplete', array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses' => 'SearchController@autoComplete'));
```

**SearchController**

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request){
    $data = Profissao::select("profissao", "id")->where("profissao","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

**html (welcome.blade.php)**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Example of Bootstrap Typeahead Autocomplete Search Textbox</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('#search_text').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get(url, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
             });
         }
     });
</script>
```

If I visit `autocomplete` it gives me the full array. If I pass the parameter `autocomplete?query=ad` it gives me the desired result.

At the `welcomepage` it shows no activity under the `network tab` and no errors. That's why I'm here. I have no clue how to debug this.

Comment: are you getting the correct value in url? dont know larvel code. And where are you inserting this script?. And you need to wrap your script contents with $(document).ready

Comment: It got me an error now (I don't know what I changed to cause this error): `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function`. Will look it up.

Comment: It is going to the right url. The script is beeing inserted right outside o fthe `<div class="row">..</div>`. No matter what library I insert it still gives me the error `typehead is not a function`.

Comment: Did you try wrapping your script with $(document).ready()

Comment: I have. I got tired and re did the entire thing and now it's woking. I have no idea where was the error. If anyone out there is having the same mistake I advise to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4F6Kcbo3Vw